# An engineering question: how can I convert a 96 bit to 18 bit

Tags: algorithms, binary

I have 262143 devices (about 18 bits counter) and each device has an unique identification code which is a 96 bits. I need a function that gets each device identification code and generates a unique number between 1 to 262143.

I will be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Presumably you are trying to avoid collisions but you do not want to just call the first one $1$, the second $2$, and so on.  This may be difficult

Comment: Thank you Henry, In our device we just need to program the software without doing any changes manually for more than 1000 devices,Does it mean there is no way to solve this problem easily?

Comment: Have you considered using hash tables? If yes, then what is the problem with implementing them in case you described?

Comment: Thank you Slup for your comment, No I have not. Could you introduce me one of them that solve this problem?

Comment: I would start by stripping the identical bits if possible (for instance all devices may be made by the same manufacturer and this manufacturer code is a fixed part of the 96 bits code). Then hash the remaining bits.